# How to use redirect_authenticated_user with extra_context in Django

Tags: python, django

I am currently using Django v1.11. What I want to happen is, If the authenticated user access the login page they will be redirect. In my case right now they can access the login page even they are authenticated.

my previous **url.py** that extra_context works is this:

```
url(r'^login/$', auth_views.login, {'extra_context': { 'all_user': User.objects.all() }}, name='login')
```

Then base from this documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView

I changed urls.py of login into LoginView.as_view() but the extra_context is not working anymore on my **registration/login.html** default template.

```
{% for user in all_user %}
    <option>{{ user.username }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^login/$', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(redirect_authenticated_user=True), {'extra_context': { 'all_user': User.objects.all() }}, name='login')
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pass the extra_content like this

```
 url(r'^login/$', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(extra_context= { 'all_user': User.objects.all() },redirect_authenticated_user=True),name='login')
```

Comment: It gives me an error, says takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given in as_view()

Comment: it is a pleasure bro, that i can help you :) , take care @keisaac